# Does using multiline in logstash filter print out the data?

Tags: regex, logging, logstash

I am trying to use multiline to combine a number of of lines in a logfile with the same starting symbol. In my case the starting symbol is #S#. it would look something like this:

```
#S# dsifj sdfojosf sfjosdfoisdjf 
#S# dsfj sdojifoig dfpkgokdfgk 89s7fsjlk sdf
#S# lsdffm dg;;dfgl djfg 930`e`fsd
...
...
...
```

Note: The random character is just use to imitate the content of the actual log.

The following is what is wrote for the multiline startment:

```
multiline {
   type => "table_init"
   pattern => "#S#"
   negate => true
   what => "next"
}
```

I am assuming what I wrote does combine them as one line, but I am wondering if this prints out the line or do I need to use gork to parse the whole entire line before it prints. Any thoughts and inputs will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to match up all lines that DO match "#S#", then you should have negate set to false. You use negate when you want to get all lines that DO NOT match a certain pattern.

As for your actual question, multiline takes all the relevant lines and puts them into the "message" field, including newline characters (\n, and I assume \r if you are running Windows as well though I have never checked). You can then grok this entire message to get the data you want.

So if you set up your output like so:

```
output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }
```

You should find that the outputted message will read something like:

```
"message" = "#S# dsifj sdfojosf sfjosdfoisdjf \n#S# dsfj sdojifoig dfpkgokdfgk 89s7fsjlk sdf\n#S# lsdffm dg;;dfgl djfg 930`e`fsd
```

if you set up your multiline filter correctly.

Hope this helps!